# Critical Regions Construct for Processes using Semaphore & Mutex (Hoare 1973)

Tags: process, queue, mutex, semaphore, monitor

Studying basic concepts of OS , I came upon this code under the topic of Critical region Constructs in high level programming languages. This was given by Hoare in 1973. I searched online but couldnt find any reference relating to this. My doubt is , why are there two queues : First delay and Second Delay ? Will just one queue do the work ?

Construct:

```
region x when (B) S;
```

With each shared variable, the following variables are associated:

```
semaphore mutex, first-delay, second-delay;
int first-count, second-count;
```

The semaphore mutex is initialized to 1; the semaphores first-delay
and second-delay are initialized to 0. The integers first -count and second-
count are initialized to 0

Code :

```
wait (mutex) ;
        while (!B) {
        first-count++;
        if (second-count > 0)
        signal (second-delay) ;
        else
        signal (mutex) ;
        wait (first-delay) ;
        first-count--;
        second-count++ ;
        if (first-count > 0)
        signal (first-delay) ;
        else
        signal(second-delay);
        wait (second-delay) ;
        second-count-- ;
    }
    S:
        if (first-count > 0)
        signal (first-delay) ;
        else if (second-count > 0)
        signal( second-delay) ;
        else
        signal(mutex);
```

Answer (score 1):

It is designed as two delays in order to avoid frequently checking condition B.
Since condition B is presumed to be affected only by S; therefore only when S is executed that we should once again check condition B. The rest threads would be stuck at either first_delay of second_delay.

Of course with only one delay would the code make sense. Try to replace all second_delay with first_delay, and eliminate the trivial ones. You may get something like this:

```
wait(mutex);
while (!B) {
    first_count++;
    if (first_count > 0)
        signal(first_delay);
    else
        signal(mutex);
    wait(first_delay);
    first_count--;
}
S;
if (first_count > 0)
    signal(first_delay);
else
    signal(mutex);
```

In this case, however, condition B would be checked over and over.

Visit [HERE](http://i.cs.hku.hk/~fcmlau/POS/lectures/ccr.html)for more details!